# Terraform conditional iteration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to create a `dynamic` resource with `for_each` as well I would like to implement a resource creation condition, however by some reason which I don't understand, the resource creation condition is not working as expected.

The logic is very simple: I've a list of objects, each object is resource, therefore in each object a have a `bool` variable that enables creation of a resource.

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "aws_asg"  {
   for_each = { for key, value in var.parameters : key => value if flatten([ for x in var.parameters : x.init ]) }
}
```

The problem in `flatten([ for x in var.parameters : x.init ])`, the resource takes first element, and ignores next element:

```
  + x = [
      + true,
      + false,
    ]
```

Here is `var.parameters`

```
   parameters = [
       # Runner 1
       {
            init    = true
            name    = "test-runner-1"

            scaling = {
                    desired     = 3
                    maximum     = 9
                    minimum     = 3
            }
       },

       # Runner 2
       {
            init    = false
            name    = "test-runner-2"

            scaling = {
                    desired     = 3
                    maximum     = 9
                    minimum     = 3
            }
       }
   ]
}
```

Any idea how to map each boolean to resource creation?

Comment: Can you share you object structure?

Comment: What is `var.parameters`?

Comment: @akortex & @Marcin I've updated the post, and included the content of `var.parameters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to conditionally loop through your `parameters`, then it should be:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "aws_asg"  {
   for_each = { for key, value in var.parameters : key => value if value.init }
}
```